# Invalid api path magento built in api

Tags: php, android, magento-1.7, android-ksoap2

I have created customized api for magento. Some built in api's call like "catalogCategoryTree" giving error: "Invalid api path" 
below are the files which I have created for custom api

api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <api>

    <resources>

      <masterapi_loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/loginmodel_api</model>
        <title>Demo Custommoduleapi API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/loginmodel</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <customerlogin translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of masterapi</title>
          </customerlogin>

        </methods>
      </masterapi_loginmodel>



       <masterapi_category translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/category_api</model>
        <title>Demo category API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/category</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <getCat translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of filters</title>
          </getCat>

          <getCProductinfo translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of filters</title>
          </getCProductinfo>

        </methods>
      </masterapi_category>



       <masterapi_catproduct translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/catproduct_api</model>
        <title>Demo Catproduct API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/catproduct</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <getCat translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of filters</title>
          </getCat>



        </methods>
      </masterapi_catproduct>



    </resources>




    <resources_alias>

      <loginmodel>masterapi_loginmodel</loginmodel>
      <category>masterapi_category</category>
      <catproduct>masterapi_catproduct</catproduct>

    </resources_alias>



    <v2>
      <resources_function_prefix>

         <loginmodel>masterapiLoginmodel</loginmodel>
         <category>masterapiCategory</category> 
         <catproduct>masterapiCatproduct</catproduct>

      </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>



    <acl>
      <resources>
        <masterapi translate="title" module="masterapi">
          <title>Loginmodel</title>
          <sort_order>5</sort_order>

          <loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
          </loginmodel>

           <category translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
          </category>

           <catproduct translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
           </catproduct>


        </masterapi>

      </resources>
    </acl>
  </api>
</config>
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycustom_Masterapi>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Mycustom_Masterapi>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <masterapi>

        <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Model</class>

        <rewrite>
           <product>Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Catproduct</product>
         </rewrite>

      </masterapi>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <masterapi>
        <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Helper</class>
      </masterapi>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">

  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />


      <complexType name="filterInfo">
        <sequence>
          <element name="filterName" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="name" type="xsd:string[]"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>

      <complexType name="fieldInfo">
        <sequence>
          <element name="entity_id" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>

      <complexType name="fieldInfoArray">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:fieldInfo[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>


      <!---Declare our types-->
            <complexType name="catalogCategoryID">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="category_id" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
       <!---Declare our input and output parameters-->
            <element name="catalogCategoryGetIDRequestParam">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="catalogCategoryGetIDResponseParam">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
            <!---here we use the type we declared earlier as our output parameter-->
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="typens:catalogCategoryID" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <!---Boohoo-->


    </schema>
  </types>


  <!-- message  -->

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="user" type="xsd:string" />
     <part name="pass" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListResponse">
    <part name="customlogin" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>

  <message name="masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />

  </message>

   <message name="catalogCategoryGetIDResponse">
        <part name="parameters" type="xsd:array" />
    </message>


   <!-- Product info Msg -->

    <message name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="category_cat_id" type="xsd:int" />

  </message>

    <message name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoResponse">
        <part name="parameters" type="xsd:array" />
    </message>
    <!-- END Product info Msg -->


  <!-- portType 2nd -->
  <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">

    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListRequest" />
      <output message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListResponse" />
    </operation>

    <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCat">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest" />
      <output message="typens:catalogCategoryGetIDResponse" />
    </operation>


     <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfo">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoRequest" />
      <output message="typens:masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfoResponse" />
    </operation>



     <operation name="masterapiCatproductGetCat">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest" />
      <output message="typens:catalogCategoryGetIDResponse" />
    </operation>

  </portType>




  <!-- binding  1st -->
  <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />


    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>

     <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCat">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>


    <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetCProductinfo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>


    <operation name="masterapiCatproductGetCat">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>

  </binding>



  <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
      <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

.php

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Mycustom/Masterapi/Model/Loginmodel/Api.php
class Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Loginmodel_Api 
{
  public function customerlogin($user,$pass)
  {

  /** @var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session */
        $session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
        Mage::app()->getStore()->setWebsiteId(1);
        try
        {
            $session->login( $user, $pass);
            $customer = $session->getCustomer();

            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'valid', 'userData' => $customer->getId()));
        }
        catch( Exception $e )
        {
            return  json_encode(array('status' => 'invalid', 'userData' => $e->getMessage()));
        }

   // return $arr_products;
   //return 'true'.$user.'+'.$pass;

  }
}
```

V2.php

```
Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Loginmodel_Api
{
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve the problem?

Comment: I got the same problem